# Boolean arrays used to prevent duplicates and syntax error problems?

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean, duplicates, playing-cards

How do I generate a new random number if validation is 1?

Can I just put another "generate number line":  `cardDrawn=(1+(rand()%52));`

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <cstdlib>;
#include <ctime>;
#include <cmath>;

using namespace std;

int main(){
int deck[52];
bool validate[52]={0};
int hand[5];
int cardDrawn;
int count=0;
int j=0;
bool repeat=0;
string cardNames[52]=   {"Ace of Clubs","2 of Clubs","3 of Clubs","4 of Clubs","5 of Clubs","6 of Clubs","7 of Clubs","8 of Clubs","9 of Clubs","10 of Clubs","Jack of Clubs","Queen of Clubs","King of Clubs",//CLUBS
                        "Ace of Spades","2 of Spades","3 of Spades","4 of Spades","5 of Spades","6 of Spades","7 of Spades","8 of Spades","9 of Spades","10 of Spades","Jack of Spades","Queen of Spades","King of Spades",//SPADES
                        "Ace of Hearts","2 of Hearts","3 of Hearts","4 of Hearts","5 of Hearts","6 of Hearts","7 of Hearts","8 of Hearts","9 of Hearts","10 of Hearts","Jack of Hearts","Queen of Hearts","King of Hearts",//HEARTS
                        "Ace of Diamonds","2 of Diamonds","3 of Diamonds","4 of Diamonds","5 of Diamonds","6 of Diamonds","7 of Diamonds","8 of Diamonds","9 of Diamonds","10 of Diamonds","Jack of Diamonds","Queen of Diamonds","King of Diamonds"//DIAMONDS
                        };//array to hold card abbreviations.

srand(time(0));
for (int i=0; i<52; i++){  // fills arrays with 1-52
deck[i]=i+1;};


cardDrawn=(1+(rand()%52));  //generates first card.
hand[0]=cardDrawn;
validate[cardDrawn]=1;
//cout << "Card 1: " << hand[0];

do{
    cardDrawn=(1+(rand()%52));
    if (validate[cardDrawn]==1)
        {
            //count doesn't update!  :D
        }
    else
        {
            hand[count]=cardDrawn;
            count++;
        }
     }while(count<4);

cout << "Card 1: " << cardNames[hand[0]];
cout << "\ncard 2: " << cardNames[hand[1]];
cout << "\ncard 3: " << cardNames[hand[2]];
cout << "\ncard 4: " << cardNames[hand[3]];
cout << "\ncard 5: " << cardNames[hand[4]];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your indentation.  The code will be much easier to understand when braces match up visibly.

Comment: It looks like `repeat` is always false, since it starts out zero and you never change it to anything else?

Comment: To expand on Ben's comment, any decent code editor/IDE (e.g. Notepad++, Emacs, Vim and Eclipse) should have an auto-indentation feature, not only making indentation easy but removing improper indentation due to human error. Auto-indentation can reveal typos when line indentation isn't what you expect.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed. Those semicolons after the `#include`s are unnecessary. Preprocessor commands don't use semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you wish to achieve is much easier using some STL. You can easily extend it to any number of cards drawn (within the same deck) with the same complexity as drawing the first.

In fact, I added 4 players, each having 5 cards in their hand. It's fairly easy to scale down to just one player. I also simplified the process of adding names for every card.

```
#include <algorithm> //random_shuffle
#include <cstdlib> //srand
#include <ctime> //time
#include <iostream> //cout
#include <string> //string
#include <vector> //vector

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand (time (NULL)); //so random_shuffle gives different values

    const vector<string> values = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    const vector<string> suits = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};

    vector<string> cards; //for names of cards

    for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; ++suit)
    {
        for (int value = 0; value < 13; ++value)
        {
            cards.push_back (values [value] + " of " + suits [suit]); //combine suit and value
        }
    }

    vector<vector<string>> playerHands (4); //4 players' hands

    random_shuffle (cards.begin(), cards.end()); //shuffle cards

    for (auto &hand : playerHands) //for each hand
    {
        for (int card = 0; card < 5; ++card) //for 5 cards
        {
            hand.push_back (cards.back()); //add last card to hand
            cards.pop_back(); //remove last card from deck
        }
    }

    int playerCount = 1; //for player's number
    for (auto hand : playerHands) //for each hand
    {
        cout << "Player " << playerCount << ":\n"; //output player number

        int handCount = 1; //for card's number
        for (auto card : hand) //for each card in hand
        {
            cout << "Card " << handCount << ": " << card << '\n'; //output card
            ++handCount; //increase card number
        }

        ++playerCount; //increase player number
        cout << '\n'; //separate players
    }
}
```

You could also either generate the list of card names each time the deck runs out, or just use a copy of `cards` for each deck (`vector<string> currentDeck (cards);`).

If this doesn't compile at all, you need C++11 and the appropriate compiler option. Otherwise, `for (... : ...)` can be replaced with `std::for_each`, `auto` can be replaced with the type, and the vector initializer lists can be replaced with a different method of constructing the vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different name for the iteration variable in the second for loop, perhaps `i2`, your problem will go away.

But I think the code you have should have been accepted under either set of for-scoping rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
j=0;
do{
    cardDrawn = (1 + (rand() % 52));
    if (validate[cardDrawn] == 0)
    {
        hand[j] = cardDrawn;
        validate[cardDrawn] = 1;
        j++;
    }
}while (j<5);
```

that probably would work

ah my bad..now must be ok

Comment: I have changed it up a little bit.

Comment: this still crashes sometimes, and gives duplicates. :[